# Ansible variable "not found" in second reference

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have a variable in a file that I reference like in a "vars_files" file. It sees to work once, then fails on subsequent references.

```
---
- hosts:  asa
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local 
  vars_files:
    - /var/lib/awx/projects/vpn/clientData

  tasks:

   - name: Build object group
     asa_config:
       lines:
         - "object network {{ client_name }}"
         - "subnet {{ app_net }} {{ app_net_mask }}" 

   - name: Build tunnel interface
     asa_config:
       lines:
         - "interface Tunnel {{ client_id }}"
         - "nameif VTI-{{ client_name }}"
         - "ip address {{ netaddr }} 255.255.255.252"
         - "tunnel source interface outside"
         - "tunnel destination {{ client_pub_ip }}"
         - "tunnel mode ipsec ipv4"
         - "tunnel protection ipsec profile PROFILE1" 

   - name: Build tunnel groups
     asa_config:
       lines:
         - "tunnel-group {{ client_pub_ip }} type ipsec-l2l" 
         - "tunnel-group {{ client_pub_ip }} ipsec-attributes"
         - "ikev2 remote-authentication pre-shared-key {{ psk_data }}"
         - "ikev2 local-authentication pre-shared-key {{ psk_data }}"

   - name: Build BGP
     asa_config:
       lines:
         - "neighbor {{ netaddr }} remote-as {{ bgp_as }}"
         - "neighbor {{ netadrr }} activate"
       parents:
         - router bgp 100
         - address-family ipv4 unicast

   - name: Save
     asa_config:
       save: yes
```

The variable is found in the "Build tunnel interface" but Ansible throws a "variable not found" in the "Build BGP" section.

```
task path: /var/lib/awx/projects/vpn/add-ecc-client-v1.yaml:35
fatal: [192.168.254.92]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'netadrr' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/var/lib/awx/projects/vpn/add-ecc-client-v1.yaml': line 45, column 6, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n   - name: Build BGP\n     ^ here\n"
}
```

vars_files content:

```
client_name: kkk
client_pub_ip: 20.1.1.11
app_net: 11.11.11.0
app_net_mask: 255.255.255.0
client_id: 1111
bgp_as: 1111


psk_data: Yh8F9FJ14mS86gOWc2MdOwjXsiqNiEJVGjicPlmzRAv0UQypJhWNNckn3YggfupxUHy0qH3QHpZ
netaddr: 169.254.100.50
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: You appear to have omitted the actual error you are receiving, and what troubleshooting attempts you have already made to solve it yourself. There is no way anyone on the Internet can _guess_ what is happening to you

Comment: I would then suggest it throws it because of `bgp_as`.

Comment: Please show the included var file with the var definition.

Answer (score 0):

Good grief . . . "netadrr" in the second refernce.

Sorry to bother

Comment: I'm glad it was something simple :-) Be aware you can delete your own questions, to save SO the trouble of closing it as "caused by typo and unlikely to help future readers"